# CodeIgniter3 - where to store PDF files?

Tags: php, codeigniter, file, pdf, codeigniter-3

I ma using CodeIgniter3 to build projects.
However I am not sure where is the best place to store generated PDF files.
I do not want to keep them in MySQL due to its size.

I do not want people to access direct links like: http://mydomain/pdf/file.pdf
but I would like to give this kind of access for codeigniter logged users.

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Outside of the application folder you can create another folder called downloads in the main directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create `site/pdf_files/.htaccess` file and add this line:

   ```
   Deny from all
   ```
2. Make router config as follows

   ```
   /*
    anything in second segment of pdf controller will be routed to
    index method 

    serve file like : 
    http://example.com/pdf/myfile.pdf
   */
   $route['pdf/(:any)'] = "pdf/index/$1";

   /*
    Note: if you got some more methods in same controller prefer below one
    because, with above one, anything in second segment will be routed to 
    index method  

    $route['pdf/display/(:any)'] = "pdf/index/$1";

    and serve files like
    http://example.com/pdf/display/myfile.pdf
   */
   ```
3. and then while serving pdf to user prefer codeigniter file helper like below

   ```
   class Pdf extends CI_Controller
   {

   function download_file($path, $name)
   {
     // make sure it's a file before doing anything!
     if(is_file($path))
     {

       // get the file mime type using the file extension
       $this->load->helper('file');

       header('Content-Type: '.get_mime_by_extension($path));  
       header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($name).'"');  // Add the file name
       header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
       header('Content-Length: '.filesize($path)); // provide file size
       header('Connection: close');
       readfile($path); 
       die();
     }
   }

    public function index($file)
    {
       // here you check whether user logged in or not

        $this->download_file('pdf_files/'.$file, $file);
    }
   }
   ```

Comment: @Tikky to make it more safe, change `function download_file($path, $name)`  to `private function download_file($path, $name)`

Comment: hello, i tried this but when using attach(), is not working, when i remove de .htacess file it works. :/

Answer (score 0):

Store the PDF outside of your document root in a location that's not public.

You can use application logic to allow logged in users to view/access:

```
class pdf extends ci_controller{

     public function view()
     {
        //check if user is logged in and has permission to view
        //set proper header information
        //readfile('non_public_path\to\pdf);
     }

}
```

As long as your pdf is outside of your public directories - sending a request to 
domain.com/pdf/view will only render the pdf if the user is logged in and has permissions to view.